# Datatables in Blazor: Dispose() doesn't work

Tags: c#, blazor, blazor-webassembly

Following a post on [DataTables.net](https://datatables.net/forums/discussion/56389/datatables-with-blazor), successfully I added DataTables.net on my Blazor WebAssembly across the application. The problem I'm facing is when I change page. As you can see in the following image, for each page with DataTables.net I change, I still have the search bar from the previous page.

[image]

In the code of each page I added

```
public void Dispose()
{
    JSRuntime.InvokeAsync<bool>("DataTablesRemove", "#tableData");
}
```

`DataTablesRemove` is defined in the `index.html`

```
function DataTablesRemove(table) {
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $(table).DataTable().destroy();
        // Removes the datatable wrapper from the dom.
        var elem = document.querySelector(table + '_wrapper');
        elem.parentNode.removeChild(elem);
    });
}
```

How can I fix this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You [have to add](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components/lifecycle?view=aspnetcore-5.0#component-disposal-with-idisposable) `@implements IDisposable` to the top of your page/component.

Otherwise Dispose() is just a method that won't be called.